# I want to display only 1 item after getting a list of items

Tags: reactjs

I have manage to get it display all the items, so it display like this

[image]

Is there a way to display it only 1 item each time I'm pressing the next and previous button? I still don't know how to do it, and I can't find keyword to research about it.

Here is my code, can someone give me some examples, guides, or some codes to help me to understand more about it, thank you.
What I'm thinking is create an array like [0->n], that's why I'm putting this.props.question into a state, when ever I click the next and previous button it'll go back and forth in an index, and it'll array the state, too, that's what I'm thinking in my head but I don't know how to write it or it's correctly or not...

```
    import {Component} from 'react'

class QuizForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            quizs: [],
            questions: [this.props.question],
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {next, previous, question} = this.props;
                console.log(this.state.questions);
        return(
            
            <div className="column middle">
            <div className="game-details-container">
                <h1> Question : <span id="question-number"></span> / 10</h1>
            </div>
                    <div className="game-quiz-container">              
                        {/* <DisplayQuestion/> */}
                                                {question} 
                        <div className="game-options-container">
                            <span>
                                <input type="radio" id="option-one" name="option" className="radio" value="optionA" />
                                <label htmlFor="option-one" className="option" id="option-one-label">A Answer</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="next-button-container">
                            <button onClick = {previous}>Previous Question</button>
                            <button onClick = {next}>Next Question</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Edit: The data of this.state.questions
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple.

> 1. `step` variable's value is used go on prev and next question index
> 2. `previous` method: decrements the step counter
> 3. `next` method: increments the step counter

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-react-class-component-lu9gjk?file=Counter.js)

### Solution:

```
  state = {
    step: 0,
    questions: [
      { id: 1, title: 'What is your name?' },
      { id: 2, title: 'What do you do?' },
      { id: 3, title: 'Where you from?' }
    ]
  };

  previous = () => {
    if (this.state.step === 0) { 
      return; // should not go back after first question
    }
    this.setState({ step: this.state.step - 1 });
  };

  next = () => {
    if (this.state.step === this.state.questions.length - 1) {
      return; // should not go forward after last question
    }
    this.setState({ step: this.state.step + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        Question: {this.state.questions[this.state.step].title}
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginTop: 10 }}>
          <button onClick={this.previous}>Previous</button> &nbsp;
          <button onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind helping, I've tried to follow your instruction, but when I'm console.log my state, which is console.log({this.state.questions}) at the render part, it's appear to be a list of each single object instead of 1 array contains all the object like the state example you showing me, how can I make my questions: [this.props.question] at the State in constructor into 1 array just like you.

Comment: @huy8856 Can you please add your this.state.questions data in the question so that I can know what type of data you have?

Comment: I've added it in the question.

Comment: Hey, I checked your data, but it is not as it should be. You have to keep all question data inside this.state.questions. So as a workaround you can loop on your data and create a question array as I have shown in the answer.